# Fetching data from WordPress database

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, wordpress, sequelize.js

Please I have a question about fetching data from a WordPress database. I am building a react application and I am required to pull username and password from an already existing WordPress site. I want to know if this is possible. If possible, what effect would making multiple requests from two sites running on different languages (php and Nodejs) have on it.

Comment: WordPress Have Plugins For Username And Password Authentication Through APIs Such As JSON API Auth. You Can Also Try JWT Auth

Answer (score 1):

On the server side you can definitely pull username and password from a WordPress database. MySQL / MariaDB is the kind of database you'll use.

A php file called [wp-config.php](https://developer.wordpress.org/apis/wp-config-php/) contains the secret credentials and other bits of information you need to connect to the database server and run queries. The server side of your react app will read that file from the WordPress installation to get that info.

Here are the lines of that file you'll need.

```php
define( 'DB_HOST', 'localhost' );          // Hostname
define( 'DB_USER', 'username_here' );      // MySQL credentials
define( 'DB_PASSWORD', 'password_here' );
define( 'DB_NAME', 'my_wp_db' );           // database name
$table_prefix = 'pf_';                     // tablename prefix
```

So, your steps.

1. Read the `wp-config.php` file and extract the data you need. You'll have to parse it somehow.
2. Using that data, open a connection to the database using, probably, the [mysql2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2) package.
3. Give a `USE my_wp_db` SQL statement (from the `DB_NAME` setting).
4. To find the user named SwiftDev from [WordPress's users table](https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description#Table:_wp_users), issue this SQL statement.

   ```sql
   SELECT user_login, user_pass
     FROM pf_users  -- pf_ comes from $table_prefix
    WHERE user_login = 'SwiftDev'
    LIMIT 1
   ```
5. If you get a resultset with no rows in it from this query, your would-be user POSTed an incorrect user name.
6. If you get a row, you'll have retrieved the `user_pass` value, the hashed password for the user you wanted. Now you're done with the MySQL or MariaDB database connection. Unless you want other stuff from WordPress.
7. If your would-be user has just POSTed a password, you will need to validate that it matches the hash. This is a bit tricky, because WordPress, having been around a couple of decades, has its own [wp_check_password()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_check_password/) function that implements the various historical hashes it's used. So you have to use Alex Albala's [wordpress-hash-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wordpress-hash-node) or some similar library in place of the usual bcrypt-style function.
8. Once you validate the password, your "would-be user" is successfully authenticated as a user.

If you want to do this user lookup and authentication directly from a client-side app, you will need to use [WordPress's REST API](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/) (maybe the [user](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/users/) endpoint) along with an appropriate [authentication plugin](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/#authentication-plugins).